# Speech Recognition - Run continuously

Tags: javascript, html, speech-recognition, html5-audio

I'm trying to create an HTML5-powered voice-controlled editor using the Speech Recognition API. Currently, the problem is when you start recording, it only lasts for a certain amount of time (basically until the user stops talking).

I can set `continuous` and `interimResults` to `true`, but that doesn't keep it recording forever. It still ends.

I can also tell it to start again during the end event, but then it asks for permission every time, which is highly disruptive.

Is there a way to allow it to go continuously while only having to ask a user once?

Answer (score 34, accepted):

No matter the settings you'll choose, Google Chrome stops the speech recognition engine after a while... there's no way around it.

The only reliable solution I've found for continuous speech recognition, is to start it again by binding to the `onend()` event, as you've suggested.

If you try a similar technique, be aware of the following:

1. If you are not on HTTPS, the user will be prompted to give permission over and over again on each restart. For this, and many other reasons, don't compromise on HTTP when using Speech Recognition.
2. Make sure you are not restarting the speech recognition immediately onend() without some safeguards to make sure you aren't putting the browser into an endless loop (e.g. two open tabs with `onend(function() {restart()})` can crash the browser, as I've detailed in this bug report: https://code.google.com/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=296690)
   See https://github.com/TalAter/annyang/blob/1ee294e2b6cb9953adb9dcccf4d3fcc7eca24c2c/src/annyang.js#L214 for how I handle this.
3. Don't autorestart if the reason for it ending is something like `service-not-allowed` or `not-allowed`
   See https://github.com/TalAter/annyang/blob/1ee294e2b6cb9953adb9dcccf4d3fcc7eca24c2c/src/annyang.js#L196

You can see how I handled this in my code - https://github.com/TalAter/annyang/blob/master/src/annyang.js

Comment: @samanime If you believe this is the most accurate answer, please mark the answer as the correct one.

Comment: Just an update. The github links seem to be broken. Here is the current link I found. https://github.com/TalAter/annyang

Comment: All links have been fixed to ones that shouldn't break with future versions of annyang

Comment: This answer is great!  the "be aware of the following" section is very useful and goes above-and-beyond what the OP was asking

Answer (score 5):

Kindly try this code, I think it does what you need:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <title>Speech recognition</title>
        <style>
            #result{
                border: 2px solid black;
                height: 200px;
                border-radius: 3px;
                font-size: 14px;
            }
            button{
                position: absolute;
                top: 240px;
                left: 50%;
            }
        </style>
        <script type="application/javascript">
            function start(){
                var r = document.getElementById("result");
            if("webkitSpeechRecognition" in window){
                var speechRecognizer = new webkitSpeechRecognition();
                speechRecognizer.continuous = true;
                speechRecognizer.interimResults = true;
                speechRecognizer.lang = "en-US";
                speechRecognizer.start();
                
                var finalTranscripts = "";
                speechRecognizer.onresult = function(event){
                    var interimTranscripts = "";
                    for(var i=event.resultIndex; i<event.results.length; i++){
                        var transcript = event.results[i][0].transcript;
                        transcript.replace("\n", "<br>");
                        if(event.results[i].isFinal){
                            finalTranscripts += transcript;
                        }
                        else{
                            interimTranscripts += transcript;
                        }
                        r.innerHTML = finalTranscripts + '<span style="color: #999;">' + interimTranscripts + '</span>';
                    }
                };
                speechRecognizer.onerror = function(event){
                };
            }
            else{
                r.innerHTML = "Your browser does not support that.";
            }
            }
        </script>
    </head>
    <body>
        <div id="result"></div>
        <button onclick="start()">Listen</button>
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: I was looking for this "speechRecognizer.continuous = true;" thanks a lot!

Answer (score 4):

> HTML 5 Speech Continuously requires this...

```js
window.SpeechRecognition = window.webkitSpeechRecognition || window.SpeechRecognition;

if ('SpeechRecognition' in window) {
  console.log('supported speech')
} else {
  console.error('speech not supported')
}
    const recognition = new window.SpeechRecognition();

    recognition.continuous = true;

    recognition.onresult = (event) => {
      console.log('transscript: ', event.results[event.results.length -1][0].transcript);
    }
    
    recognition.start();
```

Answer (score 3):

You will have to   to be rstarting the engine every few seconds.see at my code, https://github.com/servo-ai/servo-platform/blob/master/editor/src/assets/js/voice/asr.js

Note: after v 70 of chrome, a click UI is needed at least once